# Image of open unit disc under $f(z)=\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f:D\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $D$ is the open unit disc in the complex plane and $f(z)=\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^2$. I have already shown that the function is injective an complex-differentiable. However, I am stuck when trying to prove that its image is equal to the whole complex plane except the negative real line (problem with both inclusions). Does someone have an idea how to proceed? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show that $z\mapsto \frac{1+z}{1-z}$ maps the open unit disc to the open right half plane? It is normally done in steps $$z\to z-1\to \frac{1}{z-1}\to \frac{2}{z-1}\to \frac{2}{z-1}+1\to -\left(\frac{2}{z-1}+1\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x,y$ are real numbers, let $z=x + i\cdot y $ and $w=f(z)$. Denote $d=(x-1)^2+y^2$; then
$$
w = \frac{1 - 2 x^2 + x^4 - 6 y^2 + 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4}{d^2} + i \frac{-4y(x^2+y^2-1)}{d^2}
$$
First, we'll show $w$ can't be negative real or zero. Indeed, this would imply $-4y(x^2+y^2-1)=0$. But since $f$ maps $D\to\mathbb{C}$, $x^2+y^2<1$, implying $y=0$. Substituting gives $w=(1 - 2 x^2 + x^4 )/(x-1)^4 \geq 0$ and $-1\notin D$, so $w\neq 0$.

Now we'll show that if $w$ isn't zero or negative real, then $w=f(z)$ for some $z$. Note that $f(0)=1$. Write $w=\xi^2$ for some $\xi$ with $\Re(\xi)\neq0$ and solve for $z$:
$$
z = \frac{\xi-1}{\xi+1},\,\frac{\xi+1}{\xi-1}
$$ If $\Re(\xi)>0,$ then the first solution is in $D$ and vice-versa if $\Re(\xi)<0$. Then except zero and the negative real axis, $f$ maps onto $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps me a lot ! Do you also know how to show that the inverse function is holomorphic ?

Comment: I was thinking about the Inverse Function Theorem but I don’t really know how to formally use it.